# Use Laragon test sites as production

Tags: laragon

How do I make the .test site available to the world outside as a production site? I want to use this same VPS server. It has a domain name assigned to it within DNS. So, I want to go to fugizit.com externally, using the same website as fugizit.test internally.

What I've tried:

1. Copied the devel pages from C:\laragon\www\fugizit over to a production area at C:\websites\fugizit\www.
2. Set up a conf file called "fugizit.com.conf" for the production site under C:\laragon\etc\apache2\sites-enabled that refers to the production file directory.  The conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\websites\fugizit\www"
    ServerName fugizit.com
    ServerAlias *.fugizit.com
    <Directory "C:\websites\fugizit\www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That allows me to see the production site internally on the VPS when I go to http://fugizit.com/

From the outside, however, the site can still not be reached.